# Clearing Cache In Magento Removes The Cart

Tags: php, magento, caching

I've inherited a Magento project and needed only to change the value of two config variables, both payment URLs in table core_config_data.

I did so easily, but the old values persisted when loading the payment button pages. I then attempted to clear the cache by running the following:

```
$mage_filename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mage_filename;
umask(0);
Mage::run();
Mage::app()->cleanCache();
```

Now the link to the Shopping Cart is gone from the main UI. I also get 404s when attempting to add items to the cart. When displaying product pages I receive the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addExcludeProductFilter() on a non-object in /home/rcspaces/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Upsell.php on line 61
```

Please offer any suggestions you may have to help recover. Thanks.

Comment: there is no function on that class. go check Mage::log(get_class(the class that call the function addExcludeProductFilter());

Comment: Josua, you're wrong, if you look into magento 1.8 you'll notice that function in:
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Resource/Cart.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open all your log files in magento, apache, system log and exception log. Chances are one of your xml files is corrupted.

then, if you notice a error like this one:

> 2014-03-12T06:15:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the
> start of the document  in /var/www/magento1/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
>
> 2014-03-12T06:15:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():    in /var/www/magento1/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
>
> 2014-03-12T06:15:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():  ^  in /var/www/magento1/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

open up /var/www/magento1/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php, navigate to line 510 and modify loadString function to look lie this:

```
public function loadString($string)
    {
        if (is_string($string)) {


            $xml = simplexml_load_string($string, $this->_elementClass);

            if ($xml instanceof Varien_Simplexml_Element) {
                $this->_xml = $xml;
                return true;
            } else {
            Mage::log($string);
            }
        } else {
            Mage::logException(new Exception('"$string" parameter for simplexml_load_string is not a string'));
        }
        return false;
    }
```

then, clear cache (can use 'rm -rf /var/www/magento1/var/cache/' unix command) and check system log again. You should see the content of the broken xml file. fix it comparing to vanilla magento files and you should be good. my broken xml was /var/www/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/config.xml
when I reproduced the error here.

once this is working, make sure to remove the else with Mage::log($string) from the Config.php file you modified earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing server rewrite rules (.htaccess if you're on apache).

What version of Magento are you on?